# Stack level too deep in Ruby

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    name = name.to_s
    10.times do
      number = rand(100)
    end
    puts "#{number} and #{name}"
  end  
end
```

Hello, I am exercising ruby but in this nonrecursive function i am getting stack level too deep error when use this piece of code.

```
x = MyClass.New
x.try
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `number` variable defined inside `times()` falls out of `method_missing()` scope. Thus, when that line is executed Ruby interprets it as a method call on `self`.

In normal cases you should be getting `NoMethodError` exception. However, since you have overriden `method_missing()` method for `MyClass`, you do not get this exception. Instead until the stack overflows method `number(`) is called.

To avoid such problems,try to specify the method names that are allowed. For instance, lets say you only need `try, test, and my_method` methods to be called on `MyClass`, then specify these method names on `method_missing()` to avoid such problems.

As an example :

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    name = name.to_s
    super unless ['try', 'test', 'my_method'].include? name
    number = 0
    10.times do
      number = rand(100)
    end
    puts "#{number} and #{name}"
  end  
end
```

If you do not really need `method_missing()`, avoid using it. There are some good alternatives [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-dynamically-define-method.html).

Comment: You're 31 seconds faster than me. But I'd guess that `puts "#{number} and #{name}"` was supposed to be inside the `10.times` but maybe not.

Comment: You were just faster than me too! :) And I didn't think to add the bit about super (big +1), but as to the number, I think they really mean something more like this `number = Array.new(10){ rand(100) }.reduce(:+)`

Comment: yes you are right. at the moment it does not make sense to have times(), since puts is not inside the block :)